# JPA JAXRS JSON Binding deserialization error

Tags: json, rest, jakarta-ee, jackson, dto

I have a little problem with deserialization a JSON String over REST. 
My Problem is that I always get an "JSON Binding deserialization error" back.
The JSON String when get called with Chrome will be displayed in a normal way like I want. But when I want to call the Method I get the Error.

Get-REST-Method

```
public void getFilm(int id) throws IOException {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/sprint-3- 
    gruppe-1/api/actors/1");

    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder 
      = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

    ActorDTO temp = response.readEntity(ActorDTO.class);
}
```

RestAPI

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{id}")
public Response httpGetActor(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    Actor temp = actorService.read(id);
    if(temp == null)  {
        return Response.ok().entity("404 NOT FOUND").build();
    } else {
        return Response.ok().entity(new ActorDTO(temp)).build();
    }
}
```

ActorDTO

```
public class ActorDTO {
private int actorId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;    
private Date lastUpdate;

private ActorDTO() {

}

public ActorDTO(Actor actor) {
    this.actorId = actor.getActorId();
    this.firstName = actor.getFirstName();
    this.lastName = actor.getLastName();
    this.lastUpdate = actor.getLastUpdate();
}
//getter & setters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my Problem. As it seems Wildfly 14 has a Problem with "resteasy-json-binding-provider-3.6.1.Final.jar". To fix this Problem you have ignore it on loading.

Here is the solution for it:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/278678

Comment: ignoring resteasy-json-binding-provider causes change of default json marshaller from new json-b (yasson) to old jackson. its not really solution